# Obtaining .bbl file from sharelatex output

Tags: bibliographies, sharelatex, arxiv

I've just successfully (apparently) compiled a TeX document on 
sharelatex.com, using a `.bib` file as input.

But to submit to the arXiv, I require a .bbl file.
(I don't presently have access to TeXShop or similar programs.)
How might I get it? It seems that I get an `.aux` file with the output,
but no indication of a `.bbl` file.

Do I just need to wait until I have access to TeXShop?

Comment: Mhhh, I can get a `.bbl` after a successful run. You can view the `.log` files and there is an option on the bottom right (more or less) to download auxiliary files, there you can choose the `.bbl`.

Comment: Specififcally, in the output pane on the right, go to "logs and output files" (the button just next to the big *recompile* button), then go to the drop-down "other logs and files" where you can get all available files (amongst them the `.bbl` - of course that only appears if you have a bibliography set-up that needs `.bbl` files).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to shrink the webpage to see where the .bbl file was listed. Not too smart of me, not to have tried that initially. Now, I'll see if things pass arXiv muster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can download the various auxiliary files using the *Other logs and files* button:

[image]

Choosing the `.bbl` file there should prompt for a download.

Note that you don't need a front end such as TeXShop to run (La)TeX: simply installing a  TeX system (MacTeX based on the mention of TeXShop) is enough.

Comment: Currently, for arXiv to parse it correctly, it seems that the basename of the `.bbl` file should be the same as of the main `.tex` file. So if your main `.tex` file is called `main.tex`, then rename the `.bbl` file to `main.bbl` before uploading to arXiv.

Comment: As of May 2019, the BBL file should have version 2.8 so that arXiv understands it. Versions 2.9 and 3.0 can cause an error on arXiv (not in all cases; maybe not for all bibliography styles, or something). Overleaf can generate version 2.8.