# Citations doesn't show author as it should when citing in text

Tags: biblatex, citing, sharelatex

First time asking a question here, so let me know if you guys need more info.

I'm writing one of my first modular documents with sharelatex and I am having trouble with referencing sources.

I have the main file (`main.tex`) and the bibliography (`references.bib`) in the same folder with the following code in the `.bib`:

```
@book{goossens93,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
```

And the following minimalist code in `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
... bla bla bla ... \cite{goossens93}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the document the citation displays as:

> ...bla bla bla...[gossens93]

whereas I want it to show the authors name, as it should and not `[ref_key]`, preferably in APA-style. But that I can implement later on.

Comment: You need to run Biber on your document. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Try using `\addbibresource{./references.bib}` (Thus, adding `./` before the bib file name). As far as I understand, `sharelatex` should auto run `biber`, so maybe your bib file is not found. Are there any warnings or errors output?

Comment: Is the `referance.bib` in your text a typo? Your document requires `references.bib`. Make sure that the file names match up (some systems are case sensitive, so make sure to check that as well). If something goes wrong, there should be an error message. Get the `.blg` and `.log` files as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284342/35864 and post the entire `.blg` file here and the warnings/errors from the `.log`.

Comment: Any news here? Normally ShareLaTeX should run Biber for you automatically.