# APA citing gives bold display and error

Tags: biblatex

I've been searching this site over and over to find a solution to my problem, but I can't find it and what I've found does not seem to work.

My problem is as follows: I'm trying to cite APA style in my ShareLaTeX file, but whenever I type `\cite{}` and select one of the proposed writers from my .bib file, an error occurs. The citation appears in bold, and the error is:

```
Citation 'Slagter2012' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.:
You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography.
Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key
in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.
```

Now I've checked this over and over and it seems all the same to me. Is here something wrong in my file?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}    
\usepackage[american]{babel}    
\usepackage{csquotes}    
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}    
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{article.bib}    
\title{MyArticle}    
\author{MyName}    
\date{Dated: \today}    
\affil{University of Amsterdam}    
\begin{document}    
\maketitle    
\section{Introduction}    
This is the introduction.\cite{Slagter2012}    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is my .bib file

```
@article{Slagter2012,
author = {Slagter, Heleen A. and Tomer, Rachel and Christian, Bradley T. 
    and Fox, Andrew S. and Colzato, Lorenza S. and King, Carlye R. 
    and Murali, Dhanabalan and Davidson, Richard J.},
isbn = {1530-8898 (Electronic)$\backslash$n0898-929X (Linking)},
issn = {0898-929X},
journal = {Journal of Cognitive Neuroscience},
number = {9},
pages = {1932--1940},
pmid = {22663253},
title = {{PET Evidence for a Role for Striatal Dopamine in the 
    Attentional Blink: Functional Implications}},
volume = {24},
year = {2012}
}
```

And this is the output

[image: And this is the output]

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE** I am completely new to this, be as clear as possible otherwise I will not understand ;)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does the error go away if you delete the instruction `\bibliography{article.bib}` and recompile?

Comment: You need to run Biber on your document. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for explanations and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help on how to make your editor run Biber for you. If you managed to run Biber and still get an error, check the `.blg` file and post its contents here.

Comment: Okay I've looked into those links, but the thing about how to run biber does not state anything for sharelatex? I'm now trying again in MikTex (because the link does say how to run in biber there) but there, my code wouldn't even run and the error is now: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. Even though I haven't changed anyhing compared to the code above. And \begin{document} is definitely there..

Comment: ShareLaTeX should automatically run Biber for you. If this does not work on ShareLaTeX the problem must be something else, please get the `.blg` as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284342/35864 and show us the contents. If you are working on a fully updated MikTeX, you might be facing https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413898/35864

Comment: I can't add a picture but it shows a frame with nothing? I says something about performance, is that right? Yes I've removed that part..

Comment: Windows classifies `.blg` as 'Performance Monitor files', but the `.blg`s produced by Biber are just text files you can open with your favourite text editor.

Comment: I can't open it as text file, I've the ''open with'' option, but the only option is that performance monitor thingy

Comment: Then rename the file to `.txt` instead of `.blg`. But you should be able to open the file from within a text editor even without renaming it. If you can't see or change the file extension, you must first enable that: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-file-extensions-in-windows

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work.. Maybe this biber thing is still going wrong? Anyway, I can't finish this now. Maybe tomorrow or maybe I'll just give up. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: We need to see the contents of the `.blg` file to see if something is wrong with Biber.

Comment: Any news here? Could you get anywhere?