# \usepackage[block=ragged]{biblatex} not compiling

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am a Latex novice. I am using online ShareLatex and have a document which was compiling normally and I was using Bibtex as default for the literature i.e. the commands `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` to show the output. At some point I wrongly added the line `\usepackage[block=ragged]{biblatex}` in the preamble which calls Biblatex. Apart from not getting the desired result, now if I remove this line the document doesn't compile anymore (with the error "undefined control sequence"). Is there a way I can resolve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all temporary files to recompile from scratch? Follow the steps in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284342/35864 and click the little dustbin to delete all temporary files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by deleting the temporary files and recompiling.